# Sorting Poker Ranks

Tags: java

The Ranks of Poker are 2345..9TJQKA

Given an array of cards String s[] = {"Qh", "Jd", "2h"}.

I want to get back

s[] = {"2h", "Jd", "Qh"}

Here's my code:

```
         Arrays.sort(s, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare (String s1, String s2) {
            int v1 = (int) s1.charAt(0);
            int v2 = (int) s2.charAt(0);
            if (v1 == 65) v1 = 100; //changes the value of A
            if (v2 == 65) v2 = 100;
            if (v1 == 75) v1 = 85; //changes the value of K
            if (v2 == 75) v2 = 85;
            if (v1 == 84) v1 = 60;
            if (v2 == 84) v2 = 60; //changes the value of T
            return v1 - v2;
        }
    }
```

It leaves the array unchanged.

Comment: -1: "It doesn't work" is not a useful explanation, no description of your debugging effort, etc.

Comment: Note also that there are billions of questions on SO about sorting poker hands...

Comment: A person with your reputation should be able to post better questions than this.

Comment: It leaves the array unchanged.

Comment: Just ran your code and it works.

Comment: Ah, there's always magic in the air when there are magic numbers!

Comment: doesn't work for some reason. I put it in a main method.

Comment: I can confirm at least the sorting works. http://ideone.com/XX4mYP. My anwser explains why the modifying does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code using the following:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class test {
   public static void main(String... args) {
      String s[] = {"Qh", "Jd", "2h"};
      Arrays.sort(s, new Comparator<String>() {
         @Override
         public int compare (String s1, String s2) {
            int v1 = (int) s1.charAt(0);
            int v2 = (int) s2.charAt(0);
            if (v1 == 65) v1 = 100; //changes the value of A
            if (v2 == 65) v2 = 100;
            if (v1 == 75) v1 = 85; //changes the value of K
            if (v2 == 75) v2 = 85;
            if (v1 == 84) v1 = 60;
            if (v2 == 84) v2 = 60; //changes the value of T
            return v1 - v2;
         }
      });
      for (String card : s) {
         System.out.println(card);
      }   
   }
}
```

It prints:

```
2h
Jd
Qh
```

It worked for me, so maybe the problem is in the way you're invoking/using your sorting routine

Answer (score 0):

Going through the [javadocs on comparatorInstance.compare](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So, you're returning the difference between v1 and v2, seems, on the face of it, odd.

Comment: Why odd? It's a common thing in comparators.

Comment: Apparently, not common enough for me to have come across it and considered it standard practise.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your program, it's hard to say exactly what's wrong, however, you are setting yourself up for failure with your implementation of `compare`.  By having repeated `if` statements, as opposed to `if/else`, you can have two if statements execute on either v1 or v2.  Consider using a `switch`.

Another observation is that this sort of thing lends itself to encapsulation.  Why not have a Card class that hides the values of each card, instead of trying to 'translate' it inside of your `compare` method?

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying *your temporal copy* of the ASCII code for the first letter of each hand, not modifying the real strings.

Not that i'd advise to do it the way you are doing it right now, first loop to replace the strings and then sort them with your custom logic. <strike>It's O(n*2)</strike> but its still pretty fast, you arent handling millions of hands at a time, are you?

I am bored enough to do it for you:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        String s[] = {
            "Ad", "2h", "Qh" //I replaced it with an A so your replacement code can kick in
        }; //See http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif
        String mod[] = new String[s.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            int v1 = s[i].charAt(0);
            int v2 = s[i].charAt(1);
            if (v1 == 65) v1 = 100; //changes the value of A
            if (v1 == 75) v1 = 85; //changes the value of K
            if (v1 == 84) v1 = 60;
            String a1 = (char)v1 + "";
            String a2 = (char)v2 + "";
            mod[i] = a1 + a2 + "";
        }
        Arrays.sort(mod, new Comparator < String > () {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                int v1 = (int) s1.charAt(0);
                int v2 = (int) s2.charAt(0);
                return v1 - v2;
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < mod.length; i++)
            System.out.println(mod[i]);
    }
}
```

Woops, its certainly not O(n*2) as the documentation cites the sort being logn -ish, sorry.

Comment: Re: your first paragraph.  The OP doesn't want to change the strings, he/she wants to change the order of the containing array.

Comment: Oh. As running that code did yield the desired result, i assumed the OP was referring to the strings themselves not changing at all.